# Network is disabled every time I reboot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS webserver

Tags: boot, networking, server, webserver

Every time I boot up the server I have to go into recovery mode and enable networking for the server to be connected to internet.

If I don't enable network in recovery mode I get this output when I run:

```
sudo lshw -numeric -C network
```

I get this output:

```
   *-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
   [10EC:8168]
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
   physical id: 0.2
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
   logical name: enp3s0f2
   version: 0a
   serial: 08:60:6e:0f:3d:bc
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet 
   physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd 
   autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 
   driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no multicast=yes 
   port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:26 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff 
   memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

After I boot up the server and enable networking I get:

```
   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10EC$
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
   physical id: 0.2
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
   logical name: enp3s0f2
   version: 0a
   serial: 08:60:6e:0f:3d:bc
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet ph$
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversi$
   resources: irq:26 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:$
```

Comment: How and where do you enable networking in recovery mode? Is Network Manager installed and running or is networking set up in /etc/network/interfaces? If the latter, may we see the file? `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: On boot I wait for the GNU GRUB to pop up. After It pops up I select Advanced Options for Ubuntu. Then I select Ubuntu with Linux 4.40-116-generic (recovery mode). Then I select 'Network Enable networking' from the recovery menu. After it goes back into the recovery menu, I select resume from the top. Don't think I have Network Manager installed; I will try that next. Didn't outline in this guide [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free--net-2043 ) so I didn't know.

Comment: @chili555 I installed Network Manager, started it, and enabled it on reboot. Everything is working fine now. If you like, post it as an answer so I can mark this thread as solved.

Comment: I don't believe Network Manager is the best answer for a server; I think that `/etc/network/interfaces` with a static IP is best for a server. I will be happy to propose an answer if you wish.

Comment: Yes sure. If you can, please post a link or explain why you think Network Manager isn't the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend Network Manager for a server because it requires a desktop environment and a graphical interface. These take resources away from the server. As well, servers are often run headless; that is, without a monitor and then no desktop environment or graphical interface is possible.

I recommend that you set up a static IP address so that you can ssh and ftp into the server. Be certain to select an address outside of the pool used for DHCP in the router.

I suggest that you amend the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to read something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback  

auto enp3s0f2  
iface enp3s0f2 inet static
address 192.168.1.125  
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Of course, substitute your relevant details here. Either remove or at least temporarily stop Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown enp3s0f2 && sudo ifup -v  enp3s0f2
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you're all set.